# PHP: How to create a Geo-Fence(bounding Box) using the Distance from a set of Coords

Tags: php, latitude-longitude, geofencing, coords

How would i create the points of a Geo-Fence(bounding box) using lat and lon and a distance.

I have the lat and lon of the center point
I have the geofence distance.

What would the logic be to create the geo-fence around these multiple points?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Are these values coming from a geo-enabled database by any chance?

Comment: No, but I am having a look into that at the moment.

They are stored in a standard MYSQL DB

Comment: Google Haversine or Vincenty, or search here on SO for previous answers to this

Answer (score 0):

1 Convert center lat / lon to cartesian (x,y) in units meter.
Then you do all geometry as you have learned in school:

2 Create one corner point of the square, using polar coordinates formula

```
phi = 45 * TO_RADIANS;
corner.x = tcenter.x + r * sin(phi);
corner.y = tcenter.y + r * cos(phi);
```

where r is the length in meter of the half diagonal of your bounding box square

do the same for the other points by using phi =(90*i + 45), i= 0..3

3  transform corners (x/y) back to lat/lon using the inverse transformation

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lat/lon point and a distance and you want to find other lat/lon points, this is called a bearing-range problem.  See the section **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** at the website http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

If you want the box (fence) parallel to the equator, then a bearing for the north-east corner of your box will be 45 degrees (don't forget to convert to radians before using the equations).  Then add 90 degrees to get the next corner point until you have done all 4 points.