# Android position, Longitude (min, max), Latitude (min, max)

Tags: android, coordinates, distance

I have a little problem using Android.

I have my GPS position, clearly latitude and longitude, and a ray of search in meters (for example 100 meters), ok?

Imagin my position at center of the circle made by ray, I would know how to obtain on Android the:
topLeft Latitude 
topLeft Longitude 
bottomLeft Latitude 
bottomLeft Longitude

of the rectangle that inscribes the circle.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert center lat long to cartesisan x,y in meters:
   (lat lon are on a sphere, x,y is a flat map then you can continue with school mathematics

2) use polar coordinates formula to create the 4 corner points
    the first corner has angle 45 degrees, and r = 100m
    second corner of the square has angle 45 + 90 degrees

3) convert back the 4 cartesian meter coordinates to lat,lon

a bit more detailed here
[How to find a set of lat/long pairs surrounding a 5 miles radius of a certain location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599044/how-to-find-a-set-of-lat-long-pairs-surrounding-a-5-miles-radius-of-a-certain-lo/13612207#13612207)

and see my answer here

[PHP: How to create a Geo-Fence(bounding Box) using the Distance from a set of Coords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519322/php-how-to-create-a-geo-fencebounding-box-using-the-distance-from-a-set-of-co/14532162#14532162)